# Fat32 and NTFS, and bootable USB (Kubuntu)

Tags: windows-10, usb, ntfs, kubuntu, fat32

I have been trying to install Kubuntu on my Acer that has Windows 10 using a bootable USB. When i go into the install page, it informs me what formatting i want to do. I want to know if i should choose FAT32 because i do not know what will happen. I want to know if i need to choose another format, like how Windows 10 is on NTFS.

I have already looked around, and i have seen no one say what i should pick, or what the difference of FAT32 and NTFS even is.

Comment: Always choose NTFS when installing Windows

Comment: Make sure you have working, restorable backups before proceeding. I'm not sure what you're trying to do and you may end up losing data.

Comment: No FAT variant should be used for an OS install, and the only exception is for an EFI boot partition, which must be FAT32.  If installing Kubuntu, the partition for Kubuntu should likely be ext4

Comment: NTFS, FAT and exFAT file systems __COMPARISON__ https://fossbytes.com/fat32-vs-ntfs-vs-exfat-difference-three-file-systems/#:~:text=NTFS%20vs%20FAT32%20vs%20exFAT%3A%20Comparison%20%20,external%20hard%20drives%20or%20flash%20d%20...%20